# GeoJSON files being saved without line breaks

Tags: qgis, geojson, file-formats

Why are my GeoJSON files being saved without line breaks? Why are they missing the proper formatting? All features in the file are being saved in the same line.

I'm using QGIS 3.6.3.

[image]
[image: File opened in Emeditor]

**Here is what I believe is "proper formatting"**

[image]

Comment: What happens if you open your GeoJSON with Notepad++? Or alternatively: what program do you use to view it?

Comment: This "proper formatting" is just optional whitespace. Including or excluding it does not affect the validity of your JSON data.

Comment: @MrXsquared I just added a screenshot of what it looks like when I open it in Notepad and then Emeditor. The problem is I'm trying to upload the file to MapBox but it's not formatted correctly because all of the features are saved in the same line and MapBox reads that as a single feature. This is a new problem for my geojson files.

Comment: @RichardLaw I just added a photo of what I refer to as 'proper formatting'

Comment: Would you like the ability to achieve this from QGIS, or a way to format it independently of QGIS (post-export)?

Comment: There are many "pretty print" JSON tools around, here one as an example https://jsonprettyprint.org/

Comment: @RichardLaw QGIS had been saving the files in 'proper formatting' until recently - now all my geojson files have the single line. Yes, I would like to have it in the 'proper formatting'

Answer (score 1):

The [JSON format](http://json.org/) does not strictly foresee line breaks: a valid `JSON` files can be just a self-enclosed, single-line string.

It is to be noted however that (from the official [ECMA-404](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf) document)

> Insignificant whitespace is allowed before or after any token. Whitespace is any sequence of one or more of
>   the following code points: character tabulation (U+0009), line feed (U+000A), carriage return (U+000D), and
>   space (U+0020). Whitespace is not allowed within any token, except that space is allowed in strings.

One can therefore *add* line breaks (before or after tokens) to improve readability, but they are completely optional, and that is one of the reasons why most programs do not add them to their outputs.

As for importing `GeoJSON`s into **[MapBox](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/geojson/)**, they suggest a number of tools:

> There are several open source tools for converting other geospatial data formats to GeoJSON. A few favorites are:

- [togeojson](https://www.npmjs.org/package/togeojson), a node package for converting KML and GPX (XML formats).
- [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html), the ultimate 40-in-1 vector data conversion tool.
- [geojson.net](http://geojson.net/) for creating, converting, and editing GeoJSON.